# Using OracleParameter with C# TimeSpan - Literal does not match

Tags: c#, oracle, binding, parameters

I made an extensive search but I couldn't find any example about this.

I have a .NET variable of type TimeSpan and I need to put it into an `IntervalDayToSecond` record of an Oracle DB.

Referring to http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm this page, it should be possible to pass a TimeSpan object as an OracleParameter and get it inserted into my Oracle DB in a record of `IntervalDayToSecond` type.

This is the code:

```
OracleParameter t = new OracleParameter("PAR_T", _msg.t);
```

I tried it in every way, also explicitly specifying the DBType (it shouldn't be necessary):

```
OracleParameter t = new OracleParameter("PAR_T", _msg.t);
taxi.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.IntervalDS;
```

I always get the same error from Oracle:

> Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

I can't understand how to make it work; I use dozens of parameters in this application (of type `String`, `Integer`, `Date`) and they all are working. On Google I can't find a single example of someone using c# `TimeSpan` as Parameter. Has anyone ever tried this?

Comment: The documentation you cited is for Oracles classes. You seem to be using Devart instead. Try using the classes from Oracle instead.

Comment: But you seem to be using the OracleCommand from Devart. That might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer; I got your point. I'm trying using OracleCommand from Oracle and let you know. Sorry for deleting my previous comment, I'm new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was definitely my fault.
Good old `OracleParameter` was doing his job nicely; the problem was elsewhere in the query.

So I hereby confirm that it is possible to bind a TimeSpan variable to an Oracle `Interval Day To Second` record.

```
string s = "00:20";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.parse(s);
OracleParameter op = new OracleParameter("PAR_T", ts);
```

This creates a parameter named `PAR_T` which can be used in a query to insert a value into a `Interval Day To Second` record.