# Dynamic WHERE clause 'missing keyword' with apostrophe

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm dynamically generating a WHERE clause from the following DropDownList. I'm getting a **ORA-00905 missing keyword** regardless if I manually add apostrophes or not (see comment). Running the script directly on the database returns rows.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="callsInHour" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="24">24</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

...
...

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

string zcallz = callsInHour.SelectedValue;
//string zcallz =  "'" + callsInHour.SelectedValue + "'";

string whereClause = "WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)
 AND effective_Date between SYSDATE - INTERVAL :zcallz HOUR and SYSDATE 
 AND error_Reason IS NULL";


cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " +
  "acct_Id AS Account " +
  "FROM t_external_notification " +
  whereClause +
  " ORDER BY acct_Id";


cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("zcallz", zcallz));


OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EXTNOTIP"].ConnectionString);

cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

conn.Open();

cmd.Prepare();
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```

Removing the entire WHERE clause returns rows as well, so that's definitely the issue. Running a trace against the database, it appears that :zcallz is passed literally without a value. What's interesting is I have a very similar codeset running but using wildcards and it works.

```
string eventName = "%" + ddlEvents.SelectedItem.Text + "%";
```

Really scratching my head here. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add `new OracleParameter(":zcallz", ...)` - including `:`?

Comment: What is the full query executed?

Comment: @StephanBauer tried `:` without much luck.

Comment: Maybe you could use `Interval Day To Second` instead of `Interval Hour` and pass a `TimeSpan` as parameter. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320503

Comment: Instead of `SYSDATE - INTERVAL :zcallz HOUR` use `sysdate - NUMTODSINTERVAL(:zcallz, 'HOUR')`. See [NUMTODSINTERVA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thank you, that worked. Not sure I fully understand why my method wasn't working.

Comment: The `INTERVAL` expression expects only literals (1,2,3..) and **not variables**. For dynamic expression you must use the function `NUMTODSINTERVAL`.

Comment: Threre is a typo in the select statement. Remove the Comma: "acct_Id AS Account, " +
  "FROM t_external_notification "

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Add solution and I'll give it a check

Comment: @Benjamin Good catch, I was just trying to abbreviate my code when posting to SO. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `INTERVAL :zcallz HOUR` is that it is a [*interval literal*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221), i.e. you must use constant interger values, not variables.

To define a dynamic interval value, use a interval function [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

so instead of

```
 SYSDATE - INTERVAL :zcallz HOUR
```

use

```
 sysdate - NUMTODSINTERVAL(:zcallz, 'HOUR')
```

Answer (score 0):

The interval expects a string and is somewhat picky about casting and parameters.

As a work-around, this should do:

```
... BETWEEN SYSDATE - (interval '1' hour * :zcallz) AND ...
```

Comment: There is more to it I think.